# What Makes Idigam Unspeakably Alien in Practice?

Tags: lore, werewolf-the-forsaken, chronicles-of-darkness

From time to time in discussions of the setting, the Idigam are mentioned as these eldritch, unspeakably alien entities from another time. The summary about them says as much, but doesn't go into details - just describes them in abstract terms.

But are there any actual, canonical examples of Idigam known in more detail than a mere mention? What are they like? What *concrete, actual* properties thereof make them so alien? Are there any canonical examples of these entities with specific traits, abilities or behaviours that have resulted in them being described like that, and if yes, what are they and what are they like?

This question is not about *power level*, but about their unique qualitative differences that make them *hard to comprehend* (both to characters and to players) - whether universal ones, or ones specific to any named examples or subsets thereof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Alien is Easy

Coming up with an alien mentality is not too hard:  just think of your normal values and add a completely different set of priorities. These could be easy to understand or illogical.  An easy to understand one might be that a species doesn't have a concept of individual death because of the way its intelligence is distributed.  Horrible losses are acceptable to them because they aren't losses.  Or they might value the creation of art more than anything else - over pain or starvation. Harder are the illogical (to us) motivations, what TVtropes refers to as "Blue/Orange morality".  The canonical example is the "Bacon/Necktie" axis along which actions that promote Bacon are to be encouraged and the forces of Neckties to be thwarted.

The key here is that once you learn what the axes or values of the alien are, you can make reasonable assumptions about how they might act.

## Unspeakably Alien is Harder

While not a WtF player, I have researched idigama for use in my Demon: the Descent game. On p.128 of the Demon Storyteller's Guide it says:

> ...the idigam flat out terrify the Unchained. The idigam are alien proto-spirits from some time before time. They are formless and lack concept until they coalesce — losing limitless potential but trading it for powerful agency. The idigam shape essence with ease, transforming spirits to their whim and even altering physical beings to suit their whims.
>
> Each idigam is unknowable; even their simplest intentions and purposes are beyond the understanding of lesser creatures. They were somehow imprisoned on the lifeless moon or buried deep within the earth, never to be released, but they have escaped.

The next bit may be Demon splat-specific:

> Everything demons know about idigam point to a single, terrifying conclusion — idigam are aborted embryonic God-Machines who lust after their elder sibling’s power.

The Demon-splat claims that werewolves may in fact be an indirect scheme of the GM to fight off the idigam.  WtF players may feel otherwise.

As I understand the lore, the idigam were brought to Earth by the Apollo Moon landings, and so they really are something Alien.  Spirits are described in CoD:

> Animist religions describe the world as being full of spirits, with every object, animal and place hiding a spirit within it. They’re partly right; everything in the world apart from humans, even transitory events and strong emotions, does cast a spiritual reflection, but all spirits, apart from the cunning or a powerful few, are confined to a world of their own.

Idigam are immensely powerful alien "proto-Spirits" from elsewhere ("time before time").  Now imagine what spirits from Jupiter or Mars might be like - personifications of entirely alien climates, lifeforms and perhaps cultures. They are incredibly powerful and incredibly old. The spirit of Jupiter's Red Spot would somehow be constancy in change, but ever changing while remaining constant.  It would seem Mad to us because we don't have the reference points.

My favorite example of "utterly alien" in fiction comes from the Strugatsky brothers *Roadside Picnic.* To paraphrase, consider a bunch of people on a long car trip who park at the side of the road and hold a picnic.  They leave a lot of trash behind, maybe a lighter, some food scraps, and maybe a ballpoint pen. After they leave, how would a squirrel interpret it all?  How would an *ant*?  Some things are deadly, some things are tasty and some things are wondrous. In this analogy the idigama aren't the humans - they're the odds and ends left behind by the even more Incomprehensible.

## Pull a Birdbox:

Have the aliens be so *other* that looking at them is an instant Integrity break. It's comprehend what you can't see without being reduced to insanity.

Comment: Roadside Picnic is not Stanislaw Lem's.

Comment: D'oh!  Fixed it.  I was thinking of Lem's *Fiasco* as an example of utterly alien and then went with RP as a better choice since it's on Earth.

Comment: Since yours is the only answer in close proximity: are there any actual examples (very hopefully canonical) of them and if yes, are they available on the wikies, or if not, are they in some book?

Comment: Do you want me to cite WtF manual on various claims/rumors about the idigam? Or cite examples from the Onyx Patch forum?

Comment: @KieranMullen I was not pinged by your reply, so didn't realise it was there. Yes, specific canonical or posted-by-authors examples, ideally with where you found them would be nice.

Comment: @vicky_molokh  I added references to the Demon Storyteller Guide.  I am not sure how to vouch for the authority of Onyx Path forum authors.